# Hotwire Turbo does not replace turbo-frame

Tags: turbolinks, hotwire-rails, turbo-frames

I have a form

```
<turbo-frame id="goals">
    <form action="/add_goal">
        <label for="goal_name">Goal Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="goal_name" name="goal_name" placeholder="Goal name..">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Goal">
    </form>
</turbo-frame>
```

that I want to replace.

As a reply I send 303 and "Location: /added_goal" and "/added_goal" returns

```
<html>
<body>
<turbo-frame id="goals">
    OK!
</turbo-frame>
</body>
</html>
```

Turbo sets the src on turbo-frame but does not replace the content.

Comment: Post your controller action.

Answer (score 0):

Your server's response might not be correctly formatted. Given your HTML, frontend Turbo will expect something like the following:

```
<turbo-stream action="replace" target="goals">
  <template>
    <div>
      This div will replace the existing element with the DOM ID "goals".
    </div>
  </template>
</turbo-stream>
```

See [Turbo docs](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/streams), the code snippet is adapted from there.

It's unclear if you also have this issue, but you should make sure that your server is responding with Content Type `text/vnd.turbo-stream`. If the content type header isn't correct it doesn't matter if the HTML is formatted correctly.